# How to update WordPress taxonomies(categories/tags)' count field after bulk import/delete

Tags: wordpress

How to update WordPress taxonomies(categories/tags)' count field after bulk import/delete?

**Related questions:**

WordPress › Support » Fix comment and category counts after import
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-comment-and-category-counts-after-import

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to do this is by using [WP-CLI](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/). There's a command for that:

`$ wp term recount category`

Find the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/term/recount/

Answer (score 73):

This SQL helps:

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET count = (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_term_relationships rel 
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts po ON (po.ID = rel.object_id) 
    WHERE 
        rel.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
        AND 
        wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy NOT IN ('link_category')
        AND 
        po.post_status IN ('publish', 'future')
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly and very fast

Comment: I just had to add 'inherit' to last post_status array to correctly count terms for attachments

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I'm using taxonomy with media uploads. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: This worked for me for WooCommerce attributes but not for product categories. The [WP-CLI answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65219113/711006) helped with them.

Answer (score 20):

A more WordPress-compliant way would be using `wp_update_term_count_now` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)

Example:

```
$update_taxonomy = 'my_taxonomy';
$get_terms_args = array(
        'taxonomy' => $update_taxonomy,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        );

$update_terms = get_terms($get_terms_args);
wp_update_term_count_now($update_terms, $update_taxonomy);
```

Comment: I simply can't get this to work. "Argument #2 should be an array"

Comment: Function reference says it has to be a string: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term_count_now/

wp_update_term_count_now( array $terms, string $taxonomy )

Comment: But I literally used your code above, swapping out the taxonomy name.

Comment: @RobertAndrews: What happens, if you use the code above like it is, without swapping out the taxonomy name? And you could put an "echo" before "wp_update_term_count_now". Nothing is changing in your system, but the code should work without an error and "1" should be echoed.

Comment: @Martin-from-WP-Stars-com Leaving 'my_taxonomy' and prefixing `wp_update_term_count_now` with `echo` doesn't solve the "Argument #2 should be an array" problem. So, the wp_update_term_count_now line also throws it's "trying to get property of a non-object". `wp_update_term_count_now` expects your `$update_taxonomy` to be an array.

Comment: May I ask which version of WordPress and PHP you are using, @RobertAndrews?

Comment: @Martin-from-WP-Stars-com WordPress 4.9.8 with Multisite, PHP 7.0.32.

Comment: @RobertAndrews: That's weird. I tested it with WP 4.9.8 with Multisite and PHP 5.6.38, 7.0.32 and 7.1.23 and it worked always without problems. I'm afraid I cannot help you here :(

Comment: this answer worked for me. tested on WP 6.1.1, single site install, PHP 7.4.25. I placed the code inside of an init hook (`add_action('init' ....`) in my plugin.

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @kaorukobo works well. However, I needed a bit more customization to automatically update all terms for a CPT... specifically a WooCommerce product CPT with several custom taxonomies...

The following updated all the taxonomies for the product CPT.

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy tt
    SET count =
    (SELECT count(p.ID) FROM  wp_term_relationships tr
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts p
    ON (p.ID = tr.object_id AND p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish')
    WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on my Woocommerce website. I was manually setting categories to posts. This nice piece of code worked nicely after I ran after these inserts. Thanks (and thanks @kaorukobo)

Comment: This works also perfect for me after importing some product properties (terms) without WordPress functions. Thanks!

Comment: This has not corrected WooCommerce product categories for me. The [WP-CLI answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65219113/711006) helped with them.