# Update WordPress taxonomy counts

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a site with 400+ posts (using categories) and also 200 products (using a number of custom taxonomies). Somehow the count has got messed up and I can only seem to fix one or the other.

[The first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669256/how-to-update-wordpress-taxonomiescategories-tags-count-field-after-bulk-impo) fixes the categories but breaks the custom taxonomies, and the second answer fixes the custom taxonomy count but breaks the category count.

What SQL query do I need to fully count and update all taxonomies for all post types?

Comment: If you are using woocommerce, I know that there is a setting in Woocommerce > system status > tools that allows you to recount product terms. Not sure how much use that would be in this case however.  There is also [this article](http://www.weblogmechanic.com/2015/04/15/updating-term-counts-for-wordpress-and-woocommerce/) and [this one](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-category-and-comment-count-after-wordpress-import/) which cover this topic. (assuming you haven't seen them already)

Comment: Yeah, tried both of those. It seems like whenever I try to update the category count, it affects the custom-taxonomy counts with terms that have the same name - and vice versa :/