# WooCommerce Adding Parent attribute automatically

Tags: woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site with auto-imported products, which refresh them every week. These products have attributes called COLOR and SIZE.

However, the COLOR red has these sub-attributes:

- Crimson Red
- Cola Red
- Puma Red

Normally, I have to manually add and assign these sub-attributes to the "parent RED" attribute and that is a lot of work.

I wonder if there is a way to do this automatically?

For example, IF the attribute contains the word RED, assign it to parent attribute RED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be see as a strange answer. First it should help you to understand how things are going in WordPress/WooCommerce database and may be this way it could be a good alternative if you understand something about Database SQL or MySQL.

Here is explained first how WooCommerce attributes and sub-attributes are set in database:

1. When you create an attribute, it goes on DB table **`wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`**.

```css
attribute_name  attribute_label attribute_id    attribute_type  attribute_orderby   attribute_public

color           color           1               select          menu_order          0
```

2. Each sub attribute goes in DB table **`wp_terms`** (so they are **terms**). Here I have 3 sub-attributes: **`'black'`**, **`'blue'`** and **`'green'`**:

```css
term_id     name        slug        term_group

8           Black       black       0
9           Blue        blue        0
10          Green       green       0
```

3. The relationships between this main attribute and his sub-attributes is located in DB table **`wp_term_taxonomy`**. 
   Now imagine the slug of your master attribute is **`'color'`**. 
   Then for each sub-attribute **`term_id`** you will have a slug string beginning with **`'pa_`** (that mean **p**roduct **a**ttribute) + the main attribute slug **`color`**. 
   So you will get finally: **`'pa_color'`** 
   *(hope this is clear)*.
   Now in this table you have a **'count'** column that counts the number of products related to this sub-category `term_id`.

```css
term_taxonomy_id    term_id     taxonomy    description parent  count

8                   8           pa_color                0       2
9                   9           pa_color                0       1
10                  10          pa_color                0       1
```

4. In DB table **`wp_term_relationships`** you will find the relationships between products (**`object_id`** column, used by variations for example) and sub-attributes (**`term_taxonomy_id`** column). As you can see on the example below, the sub-attributes are used by 2 products (`object_id`):

```css
object_id   term_taxonomy_id        term_order

22          8                       0
40          8                       0
40          9                       0
22          10                      0
```

> **A SQL solution**: 
>   For you if you can alter database tables, the useful table to alter is **`wp_term_taxonomy`** DB table.
>
> 1. Search all sub-attributes **`term_id`** in **`wp_terms`** DB table.
> 2. Compare them to existing **`term_id`** in **`wp_term_taxonomy`** DB table
> 3. Create for all non existing **`term_id`** in **`wp_term_taxonomy`** with the correct **`'taxonomy'`** slug for each one.
>
> This is possible with SQL queries through PHP *(that you will need to fine tune to feet your very specific needs)*.

I hope this will help you a bit.

Some useful threads, related to SQL **`wp_term_taxonomy`** :

- [How to update WordPress taxonomies(categories/tags)' count field after bulk import/delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18669257/3730754)
- [SQL to update custom post taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139241/79855)

  [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) [woocommerce](/questions/tagged/woocommerce) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) [database](/questions/tagged/database) [tables](/questions/tagged/tables)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Will look into it